# how to join text column based on the difference of others columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
       top   bottom                      fontname    size       x0       x1                           text
0   62.890   73.890  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000  321.730  520.115  RISK MANAGEMENT AND INTERNAL 
1   76.893   87.893  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000  321.730  376.334                        CONTROL
2  146.897  157.897  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000   76.535  203.662              COMPANY SECRETARY
3  272.913  283.913  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000   76.535  222.593          INDEPENDENT AUDITORS 
4  286.916  297.916  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000   76.535  167.164                   REMUNERATION
```

I want to

1. join the text of `row[i].text` and `row[i+1].text` if `abs(row[i].bottom - row[i+1].top) < row[i].size`
2. replace `joined_text` to `row[i].text`
3. replace `row[i].bottom` to `row[i+1].bottom`
4. discard `row[i+1]`

For example:

- `row 0` has `text`: `RISK MANAGEMENT AND INTERNAL`
- `row 1` has `text`: `CONTROL`
- `row 0` and `row 1` both have same `size`: 11
- `abs(row[0].bottom - row[1].top)` is 3.003

Because `3.003 < 11`

- desired `row[0].text` is `RISK MANAGEMENT AND INTERNAL CONTROL`
- desired `row[0].bottom` is `87.893`
- `row[1]` is removed from the dataframe

For clarity, the desired result is the following:

```
       top   bottom                      fontname    size       x0       x1                           text
0   62.890   87.893  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000  321.730  520.115  RISK MANAGEMENT AND INTERNAL CONTROL
1  146.897  157.897  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000   76.535  203.662  COMPANY SECRETARY
2  272.913  297.916  HNGMRP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd  11.000   76.535  222.593  INDEPENDENT AUDITORS REMUNERATION
```

It is what I attempted:

```
def df_section_text(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df_title_text = self.df_title_text
    df_next_title_text = self.df_title_text.shift(-1).dropna()
    df_section_text = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for next_title, title in zip(df_next_title_text.itertuples(index=False),  df_title_text.itertuples(index=False)):
        diff_btw_titles = abs(title.bottom - next_title.top)
        
        if diff_btw_titles < title.size:
            title = pd.DataFrame([title]).to_dict()
            title['bottom'][0] = next_title.bottom
            title['text'][0] += next_title.text
            title = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(title)
        
        df_section_text = df_section_text.append([title])
    
    df_section_text = df_section_text.drop_duplicates(subset=['bottom']).reset_index()
    return df_section_text
```

where `self.df_title_text` is the problem dataframe presented above.

It is  slow when the row number increases. Is there another faster and more elegant way that produces the desired result? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try use `shift` with `cumcount` get the subgroup then we just need to based on that key do `groupby` with `agg`

```
s = (df['bottom'].shift()-df['top']).abs().gt(df['size']).cumsum()

out = df.groupby(s).agg({'top':'first',
                         'bottom':'last',
                         'fontname':'first',
                         'size':'first',
                         'x0':'first',
                         'x1':'first',
                         'text':' '.join})


out
Out[20]: 
       top   bottom  ...       x1                               text
0   62.890   87.893  ...  520.115  RISKMANAGEMENTANDINTERNAL CONTROL
1  146.897  157.897  ...  203.662                   COMPANYSECRETARY
2  272.913  297.916  ...  222.593   INDEPENDENTAUDITORS REMUNERATION
[3 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: It is an excellent answer. In addition, because the type of `top` and `bottom` is `Decimal`: `s = ((df['bottom'].shift() - df['top']).abs() > df['size']).cumsum()` will avoid the error `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`.